# Sorting data with fetch

Tags: javascript, sorting, fetch

I need your help. With the help of fetch, I get the data and immediately draw them. On the button I want this data to be sorted, however I receive an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
<button id="sort_by_name">Sort</button>
```

JavaScript

```
fetch(`https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
        let vino = data[i]
        let a = document.getElementById('sort_by_name');
        a.addEventListener('click', () => {
            data.sort((a,b) => a.wine - b.wine)
        })
        document.write(`<div>${vino.wine}</div>`)
    }
})
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I receive an error"? What's the error?

Comment: The order you are doing things in is so messed up I don't know where to begin. Seriously think about what you want to happen, when you want those things to happen, and how many times you want each of them to happen.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: You should not put `getElementById()` and `addEventListener()` code inside loop I think it should be outside of for loop. And you should also post your error.

Answer (score 0):

[sort and search method using fetch api](https://medium.com/@miter.ani/let-page-1-let-arr-const-secboxs-document-queryselector-services-boxs-2bbcb7cd532f)

```js
let productContainer = document.querySelector('.product-container')
let arr_1 = [];
let arr_2 = [];
let search = document.querySelector('#search')
let sortBtn = document.querySelector(".sort");
function getDataJson() {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/services`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            arr_2 = data;
            productContainer.innerHTML = "";
            arr_1 = arr_1.length || search.value ? arr_1 : data;
            arr_1.forEach(element => {
                productContainer.innerHTML += `
            <div class="product-boxs">

            <div class="product-image"><img src="${element.images}" alt=""></div>
            <h2>${element.title}</h2>
            <h2>${element.price}</h2>
            <div class="product-icons">
                        <span>5<i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></span>
                        <span>5<i class="fa-solid fa-heart"></i></span>
            </div>
            <p>${element.description}</p>
            <div class="product-btn">
            <button class="card">Card</button>
            <button class="details" ><a href="details.html?id=${element.id}">View</a></button>
            </div>

            </div>
            `

            });
        })



}
getDataJson()
search.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    arr_1 = arr_2;
    arr_1 = arr_1.filter((el) => {
        return el.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())
    });
    getDataJson();
})
sortBtn.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
    if (e.target.value === "za") {
        arr_1.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
    } else if (e.target.value === "az") {
        arr_1.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price);
    } else {
        arr_1 = []

    }
    getDataJson(); // Update the displayed data after sorting.
});
```

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add a click listener to the button.
2. Get the data, and store it in a variable.
3. Display the data. Simplest way possible is by using `.innerHTML` but you could also learn how to use `.appendChild`.
4. To sort the list, use `.localeCompare`.

```js
let wineList;

document.getElementById('sort_by_name').addEventListener('click', sortList);  // 1

fetch(`https://api.sampleapis.com/wines/reds`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  if (data) {
    wineList = data;     // 2
    display(wineList);   // 3
  }
})

function display(list) { // 3
  const wineDataEl = document.getElementById('wine_data');
  let htmlStr = '';
  
  for (const wine of list) {
    htmlStr += wine.wine + '<br/>';
  }
  
  wineDataEl.innerHTML = htmlStr;
}

function sortList() {    // 4
  if (wineList) {
    wineList.sort((a, b) => a.wine.localeCompare(b.wine)) ;
    display(wineList);   // 3
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="sort_by_name">Sort</button>

<div id="wine_data">Loading...</div>
```